How some premiere pro extensions copy and paste in timeline without cover the clip？
I recently develop a extensions which can use extensions to copy some clips from one sequence to another,but i found that new 2022 pr will cover the clip in the timeline.I acxtaully use a hot key like control c and v to make this function work.But i found some other extesions like atomx or mr horse,no matter what the pr shortkeys set,paste will never  cover the clip.And i am sure that they use a dll or exe something like that.How can i do this?Is there any ways?
copy and paste without cover the clip in sequence before.
